# Replication from MySQL 5.0 to MariaDB 10.2.8 - Unknown system variable 'binlog_checksum', Internal MariaDB error code: 1193

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, mysql-5.0

We are **finally** upgrading our MySQL 5.0.90 environment to MariaDB, and we would like to enable replication from MySQL 5.0 to MariaDB 10.2.8 and then cutover thus providing minimal downtime. I tried this originally with MariaDB 10.1.18 and it worked fine. MariaDB 10.2.8 became GA so we moved our upgrade process to that version. Now when I try to begin replication I get the following error in the MariaDB mysqld.err log:

`Unknown system variable 'binlog_checksum', Internal MariaDB error code: 1193`

When I execute 'show slave status' I see the following:

```
Slave_IO_Running: No
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes

Last_IO_Errno: 1595
Last_IO_Error: Relay log write failure: could not queue event from master

Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
```

I've tried to do some research on this but have been unable to resolve the problem.

Here is the entire section of the log where replication is starting.

`2017-11-20  8:26:43 140154253575936 [Note] Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'mysql-bin.002735' at position 98, relay log './mysqld-relay-bin.000001' position: 4
2017-11-20  8:26:43 140154252973824 [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master 'repl@scvm50.dev.ut1.omniture.com:3306',replication started in log 'mysql-bin.002735' at position 98
2017-11-20  8:26:43 140154252973824 [Warning] Slave I/O: Notifying master by SET @master_binlog_checksum= @@global.binlog_checksum failed with error: Unknown system variable 'binlog_checksum', Internal MariaDB error code: 1193
2017-11-20  8:26:43 140154252973824 [ERROR] Slave I/O: Replication event checksum verification failed while reading from network, Internal MariaDB error code: 1743
2017-11-20  8:26:43 140154252973824 [ERROR] Slave I/O: Relay log write failure: could not queue event from master, Internal MariaDB error code: 1595
2017-11-20  8:26:43 140154252973824 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'mysql-bin.002735', position 98`

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution/workaround. I need to set the variable slave_sql_verify_checksum=0 on the slave (MariaDB 10.2.8). I was trying this by dynamically setting the global variable on the slave but it wasn't working. Then I found bug [#MDEV 8505](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-8505) which indicates that resetting the variable dynamically does not work. Once I set it in the my.cnf and restarted the instance, everything started working as expected. Thankfully this is only a interim solution until we complete the upgrade!

Answer (score 2):

5.0 to 10.2 is about 4 major jumps.  So, I am not surprised that you encountered a problem.  If you like, file a bug with MariaDB about it.  Normally a newer Slave will successfully replicate from an older Master.  But I guess this is too far.

May I suggest that you go with 10.1 for the time being.  This will be a significant upgrade for now.  You may have subtle issues yet to discover.  Then plan on 10.1 to, say, 10.3 next year.

The manual also says "Bug #61096 ... If backward compatibility with older slaves is a concern, you may want to set the value explicitly to NONE."

And ----- 2016-07-04 MariaDB 10.2.1 -- -- [MDEV-8429](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-8429) : Change binlog_checksum default to match MySQL 5.6.6+

And see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_master_verify_checksum